# Regex - exclude domain

Tags: regex

Lets say, I have domain

```
@abc.com.
```

I need to match the pattern if there are 3 or more external recipients.

For example:
To:

> user1@abc.com; external@contoso.com; user2@abc.com; user3@abc.com;
>   user4@abc.com; user5@abc.com; external2@contoso.com; test@google.com

The regex I already have looks like that:

```
To:(.*@[^a][^b][^c][^.][^c][^o][^m].*){3,}
```

Its kinda working, but looking nasty.
Maybe somehow implement this?  `^((?!@abc.com).){3,}`

Thank you!  It would help me a lot

Comment: Do you mean [`^(?=(?:.*\bexternal){3}).*`](https://regex101.com/r/uG2jV2/3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match:

1. A `"@"`
2. not followed by `"abc."`
3. more characters until the next `"@"`
4. (1), (2) and (3) repeated 3 times

This expression will match a subject with 3 external recipients:

```
(?:@(?!abc[.]).*?){3}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oY1vI7/1)

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It uses the [negative lookahead](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!abc[.])` to check it's not followed by your domain. The `.*?` is there to comsume the chars between different `@`s.

You may as well change `abc[.]` to `abc[.]com(?:[; ]|$)` or your real domain.

Comment: Im testing your codes on regexp.cz
so far none of them works..
testing string: 
To: user1@abc.com; external@contoso.com; user2@abc.com; user4@abc.com; user5@abc.com; external2@contoso.com;external@contoso.com;external@contoso.com
after hitting "GREP" button, the result should match if there are more external recipients..

Comment: grep does not support [lookaheads](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). You should really specify your programming/scripting language or tool by tagging your question. Are you using grep from command line?

Comment: It is REJECTED match for postfix, if there are more than n count number of external recipients.  Just to be clear

Comment: Can you use Perl or PCRE as regex flavour? Where will you use this? Command line grep, a script, what language?

Comment: http://mattshaw.org/news/how-to-filter-mail-with-postfix-header_checks/
action will be REJECT if x number of ext recipients   (local ones can be infinite)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, but you can try changing `main.cf` to `header_checks = pcre:<<filename here>>`. You have to use PCRE, or perhaps someone else can help you there.

Comment: Thank you Mariano, u helped a lot!

Comment: No problem. You may try asking a different question: "how to use PCRE in header_checks", properly tagged in whatever it's you''re using, linking to this post.